# opentelemetry-collector-contrib to exporter traces on datadog

Tags: validation, key, datadog

I am configuring opentelemetry-collector-contrib to export traces on datadog.

I tried this below references :

1. https://docs.datadoghq.com/opentelemetry/
2. https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/datadogexporter/examples

getting error:

> Error while validating API key datadog", "error": "Get "https://api.datadoghq.eu/api/v1/validate": Not Found"}